# BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher when device turn off BLE - UWP

Tags: uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal, gatt

**What I have done:**

1. I have an observable collection `Display`.
2. When I get `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received` event, I check the RSSI.
3. If RSSI > -65DBm, I add the device in `Display`.

   (RSSI goes like -60 > -127 > -57 > -127 > -63 > -127 >...... I'm bit curious if this normal)

---

**Question:**

> Can I 'catch' when the user **turns off BT/BLE of the device**?
>
> - so I can **remove the corresponding device from `Display`**.

The only events are `Received` and `Stopped` that I don't think it's possible like [devicewatcher](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario1_Discovery.xaml.cs) does, but still...

If this is not possible, that's fine too; please just comment/answer "This can't be done" so I don't dig in for nothing :)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you add `SignalStrengthFilter` for device watcher?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment! I did add the filter, but since the observable collection I created is not binded to the watcher (i.e. I need to manually add/remove obj from the list), I felt it's meaningless. Is there a way I can catch whether a **specific device** is considered to be out of range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> RSSI goes like -60 > -127 > -57 > -127 > -63 > -127 >...... I'm bit curious if this normal

This is normal and it base on your bluetooth device sensitivity. if you have set the following, He will filter out mismatched data. But for my testing `-127` will be capture with watcher.

```
watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.InRangeThresholdInDBm = -70;
watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeThresholdInDBm = -75;
```

> If RSSI > -65DBm, I add the device in Display

You could get RSSI value in `OnAdvertisementReceived` event handler with `eventArgs.RawSignalStrengthInDBm`. And then do secondary filtering.

```
Int16 rssi = eventArgs.RawSignalStrengthInDBm;
if (rssi >= -65)
{
 // add to collection.
}
```

> Is there a way I can catch whether a specific device is considered to be out of range?

Currently, there is no such api to detect the specific device is out of range.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanation! I should've mentioned more clearly that the steps above are what I'm currently doing (i.e. already done); thank you anyway for the second part. **Back to the story, so the RSSI behavior is normal and CURRENTLY THERE IS NO WAY TO DETECT WHETHER A SPECIFIC DEVICE IS OUT OF RANGE OR NOT.** Cool cool! thank you so much for your help. Hope you have a wonderful day :)